# Ambiguous reference to member 'putData' error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Making a simple app that involves uploading pictures but I can't figure out how to get by this error.  Yes I'm super new to swift and firebase.

```
 guard let image = self.plusPhotoButton.imageView?.image else { return }
        guard let uploadData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) else { return }

        let filename = NSUUID().uuidString

        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child(filename)
        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, err) in

            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to upload profile image:", err)
                return
            }
        },
        storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (downloadURL, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to fetch downloadURL:", err)
                return

            }
            guard let profileImageUrl = downloadURL?.absoluteString else { return }

            print("Successfully uploaded profile image:", profileImageUrl)
        })


    )}
    }
```

Got this error:

```
Ambiguous reference to member 'putData'
Expressions are not allowed at the top level
Use of unresolved identifier 'uploadData'
Expected ')' in expression list
```

Answer (score 2):

**There is one error in brackets Closing.**

```swift
guard let image = self.plusPhotoButton.imageView?.image else { return }
        guard let uploadData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) else { return }

        let filename = NSUUID().uuidString

        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child(filename)
        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, err) in

            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to upload profile image:", err)
                return
            }
        },
        storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (downloadURL, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to fetch downloadURL:", err)
                return

            }
            guard let profileImageUrl = downloadURL?.absoluteString else { return }

            print("Successfully uploaded profile image:", profileImageUrl)
        })


    )}  //Replace With }) 
}
```